# ZF2 BBCode Parser

Tags: zend-framework2, bbcode, renderer

Hiho,
I use the ckeditor on my website for special textareas like forum
or signatures. 
But I have a problem with the output. I use ZF2 and would like to
use ZendMarkup to render the output bbcode back in html.
But at every time I call 
    $bbcode->render(...)
I got the error 
    There is no Zend_Markup_Root markup.
The ZendMarkup is an extension inspired by the Zend_Markup from ZF1.
But I can't find any thing on API or other guides.
Does someone has any idea what as the problem is?

Comment: At least provide Links to this ZendMarkup-Module as well as the concrete Error-Message.

Comment: the Link is: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendMarkup  The concrete error message is the one above. It is an exception which is thrown. The $bbcode is: $bbcode = Markup::factory('Bbcode'); . If I call special the bbcode-parser with $bbcode = new Bbcode(); as new Instace of ZendMarkup\Parser\Bbcode I got the error "There are no groups defined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZendMarkup library is *very* old (last update is 10 months ago!) so I wouldn't use such library. If you would like, I think I traced the error down.

On [this line](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendMarkup/blob/master/library/ZendMarkup/Parser/Bbcode.php#L67) there is a reference to `Zend_Markup_Root` while that should be `ZendMarkup\Renderer\Markup\Html\Root`. Try to change that line and see what happens.

Another way is to replace the ZendMarkup library with another library which does work and is updated regularly. An example is [Decoda](https://github.com/milesj/Decoda). If you load `mjohnson/decoda` in your composer.json, you can use Decoda in your Zend Framework 2 application:

```
<?php
use Decoda\Decoda;

$parser = new Decoda($bbcode);
$html   = $parser->parse();
```

With tools like composer, there is no need to use solely Zend* components when there are better alternatives.